# Convert IP Address to Coordinates using database

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file which contains IP and I wanted to compare it to Coordinates using a local database (instead of API).

I tried following a process and break down to pieces and created scripts referring to various articles.

**Coordinated Database file:**

```
16777216 16777471 AU Australia Queensland Brisbane -27.467940 153.028090
16777472 16778239 CN China Fujian Fuzhou 26.061390 119.306110
16778240 16779263 AU Australia Victoria Melbourne -37.814000 144.963320
16779264 16781311 CN China Guangdong Guangzhou 23.116670 113.250000
```

**IP Address File:**

```
131.72.136.65
131.72.138.204
131.72.138.45
131.72.139.112
131.72.139.163
```

So first I modified IP to decimal so I can compare.

**IP2Dec**

```
#!/bin/bash
# while read line; do echo  "$line"; done < iplist.txt
ip2dec () {
    local a b c d ip=$@
    IFS=. read -r a b c d <<< "$ip"
    printf '%d\n' "$((a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d))"
}

ip2dec "$@"
```

I compared IP and DB file and printed the IP, Lat, Long using the script below.

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1] = $1+0; next; } { for (i in x) { if (x[i] > $1+0 && x[i] < $2+0) { print x[i], $NF-1, $NF;} } }' ip.txt db.txt
```

So now the output is,

```
387306133 -78.4875 -77.487490
399341146 -105.985 -104.984700
399478903 -105.985 -104.984700
401285510 -123.395 -122.395200
401289024 -123.395 -122.395200
520966134 102.85 103.850070
```

Now I wanted to convert Decimal back to IP address,

```
    #!/bin/bash
dec2ip () {
    local ip dec=$@
    for e in {3..0}
    do
        ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
        ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
        ip+=$delim$octet
        delim=.
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ip"
}
    dec2ip "$@"
```

But this converts entire file, I just want to convert first column and retain the Lad and Lon.

I trying to combine all these bits and pieces to do a single job.

Also, is this an efficient way of doing? Ultimately I want these IP to be plotted on Google Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except the IP2Dec and dec2ip script, which need to
be performed only on part of the file, it should work.
Here an example of dec2ip which applies the function only on
the first entry of the line.

```
#!/bin/bash
dec2ip () {
        local ip dec=$@
        delim=""
        for e in {3..0}
        do
                ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
                ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
                ip+="$delim$octet"
                delim=.
        done
        printf '%s' "$ip"
}

while read IP lon lat ; do
        dec2ip $IP
        printf " %s %s\n" "$lon" "$lat"
done
```

A better way would be to write everything in a short way in a higher level language.
The following python 2.7 script should perform the task you need (it is not optimized
for speed):

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
import socket,struct
db=[]
for l in open("db.txt"):
    fields=l.split();
    db.append((int(fields[0]),int(fields[1]),fields[-2],fields[-1]))

for l in open("ip.txt"):
    ip=struct.unpack('!I',socket.inet_aton(l))[0]
    for e in db:
        if e[0]<=ip<=e[1]:
            print l.strip(),e[2],e[3]
            break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Python script just works as expected. I could still find it very fast comparing to the AWK script which I used. DB file is of 200K lines.